# How run command in CMD with administrator privileges in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

How to run command in CMD with administrator privileges after user clicks install on NSIS? I use Zip2Exe.

Answer (score 0):

Am I mistaken in thinking that installers ask for these permissions anyway?
Either way it looks like you may be out of luck you might have to use makensis instead.

https://nsis.sourceforge.io/mediawiki/index.php?title=Zip2Exe&oldid=4446

> It only allows you to set some very basic installer options like the
> name, directory and compression method. It's not possible to add a
> license, sections, script code etc.